# How do I add a user group in the latest edition of Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows, windows-10, users, windows-10-v1511, user-groups

The newest version of Windows 10 Home (version 1511) brings with it a whole slew of new stuff. It also brings with it its own handful of problems.

One of these is the apparent inability to create user groups. The [method for Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/user-groups#1TC=windows-7) that Microsoft documents works for systems running 7 and a number past that; it worked on my Windows 8, 8.1 and previous versions of 10.

However, in the current version of 10, the `lusrmgr.msc` Microsoft Management Console snap-in is unavailable. This is the way adding a group would normally be done.

Lacking this function, how can I add a security (user) group in the latest edition of Windows 10 Home?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 edited in. 1511.

Comment: Ahh, I just re-read. It's not that the newer build of Windows 10 doesn't have it, it's that Windows' Home editions NEVER had it (not Windows 7 Home, not Windows 8 Home), see the answer(s) on the duplicate... :)